# Converting from Viewport3D to IUIComponent using papervision3D & Flex together

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, 3d

I'm developing using Eclipse Indigo, Flex 4.5.1, Papervision 3D 2.0.883.  Basically what I'm trying to do is get [this papervision3D/Flex example](http://www.cornflex.org/files/video3d/srcview/index.html) to compile so I can use it for a movie viewer on my own site.  I've had to make a bunch of changes to get it to work with Papervision 3D 2.0, so that may be part of the problem.  My application spits out the following complaint when I run it in Flash Debugger:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert org.papervision3d.view::Viewport3D@2bf6df49 to mx.core.IUIComponent.
    at mx.core::Container/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::addingChild()
    at mx.core::Container/addChildAt()
    at mx.core::Container/addChild()
    at SphericVR/init()
    at SphericVR/___SphericVR_Canvas1_creationComplete()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()
```

Two bits of the code that are what I believe to be responsible:

```
public function init( event:Event):void
                {   
                    container = new UIComponent();      
                    container.x = (this.width)/2;
                    container.y = (this.height)/2;                  
                    canvasPv3D.addChild( container );
    //a bunch of mouse-movement stuff, and adding a video display
                    init3D();
                    container.addChild( viewport );
    //some event listeners
    }
```

and the other function that is referenced above:

```
 private function init3D():void
                {
                    viewport = new Viewport3D(canvasPv3D.width, canvasPv3D.height, true, true);
                    addChild(viewport);

                    scene = new Scene3D();
    //adding camera, renderer, creating a bitmap material, mapping material to a sphere

                    scene.addChild( sphere );
                    canvasPv3D.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop3D );
                }
```

Comment: Show some code in addition to the error.  I believe PaperVision is an ActionScript framework with no Flex dependencies.  It seems like you are trying to reference an PaperVision class (ViewPort3D) with an interface (IUIComponent) that it doesn't implement.

Comment: Why are you using PaperVision anyways?  It's been out of development for years... There are many new alternatives like Away3d or alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

As www.Flextras.com suggest, the issue is the flex component you're trying to add viewport to (Canvas) expects a Flex component, which Viewport3D is **not**.

A quick and dirty trick is to add the viewport to **rawChildren** and be done with it.
I suppose a slightly cleaner way to do this is to have a UIViewport3D class which extends Viewport3D, but also implements the UIComponent required properties and methods.

Have a look at other [PV3D & Flex](http://unitzeroone.com/blog/2006/12/12/papervision-3dflex-2-example-flex-makes-its-first-pv3d-steps/) [examples](http://blog.papervision3d.org/2007/10/04/tinks-papervision3d-effects-for-flex/) for some ideas.

As J_A_X mentioned, PV3D isn't developed anymore, so Away3D for example would be a better alternative. There is a pretty good tutorial for [Away3D and Flex](http://www.flashmagazine.com/tutorials/detail/using_away3d_with_flex/) you could use:
[image: Away3D_Flex]

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks!  I'm new to Flex & Papervision was simply one of the first tutorials I found for doing 3D.  I'll try Away3D!

Comment: Glad that helps! Feel free to vote/mark this answer if you find it useful ;)